# License problem using sectioned ListView with J. Sharkey's SeparatedListAdapter

Tags: android, listview, licensing, adapter, sections

big explanation (better safe...), question in bold if you don't want to read it all. Thanks a lot for your help!

I have an app with a `ListView`, and two custom XMLs. One is a single TextView, for the headers. The other has 3 TextViews and 3 ImageViews that represent the data.

As most of you know, [Jeff Sharkey](http://jsharkey.org/) already has a [very clever (imho) solution](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) (`SeparatedListAdapter`), which allows the class to work, without modifications, with ImageViews. Although it accepts `String`s, I can provide the `valueOf` of the drawable int resources, and it will figure it out. Great, see code and screen at end (his class not here for simplicity).

The problem is that, **for my project, I've been given a stack of in-house, proprietary code to work with. And Sharkey's code is GPLv3, which rules out the possibility of me using his code. So maybe you could know a solution that would allow me to link to that code without my other code being "attracted" to the force of the GPL**. I'm not discussing the politics of it, so I appreciate if you don't. Besides, I'm not circumventing, I'm avoiding it legally.

Right now, I've been able to find [cwac-merge](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge), which is ASL 2. But so far I couldn't "map" the strings and drawables to custom TextViews and ImageViews in a custom XML layout. Also, the example app uses a completely different approach to what I think I remotely need.

In case you care to see what I'm up to, see `SeparatedListAdapter` and my class below. For cwac-merge, it force closes no matter what, so I won't bother posting.

```
package com.uitests;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class TestActivity extends ListActivity {

public final static String ITEM_TITLE = "title";
public final static String ITEM_STATE = "state";
public final static String ITEM_TEMPERATURE = "temperature";
public final static String ITEM_UP = "up";
public final static String ITEM_DOWN = "down";
public final static String ITEM_LEVEL = "level";

public Map<String,?> createItem(
        String title, String state, String temperature, 
        String upImage, String downImage, String levelImage) {  

    Map<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();  
    item.put(ITEM_TITLE, title);  
    item.put(ITEM_STATE, state);
    item.put(ITEM_TEMPERATURE, temperature);
    item.put(ITEM_UP, upImage);
    item.put(ITEM_DOWN, downImage);
    item.put(ITEM_LEVEL, levelImage);
    return item;  
}


@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {  
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE TO POPULATE THE LIST FOR STACKOVERFLOW!

    List<Map<String,?>> controlA = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();  
    controlA.add(createItem(
            "Monitor 001AK", 
            "Functional", 
            "27", 
            String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_up),
            String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_down_off),
            String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_level07)));
    // MORE .adds HERE

    List<Map<String,?>> controlB = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();  
    controlB.add(createItem(
            "Monitor 003CK", 
            "Functional", 
            "29", 
            String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_up),
            String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_down_off),
            String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_level07)));
    // MORE .adds HERE

    SeparatedListAdapter adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);  

    adapter.addSection(
            "Control 1", 
            new SimpleAdapter(
                    this, 
                    controlA, 
                    R.layout.equip_row,  
                    new String[] { 
                            ITEM_TITLE, 
                            ITEM_STATE, 
                            ITEM_TEMPERATURE, 
                            ITEM_UP, 
                            ITEM_DOWN, 
                            ITEM_LEVEL }, 
                    new int[] { 
                            R.id.tide_row_title, // TextView
                            R.id.tide_row_state, // TextView 
                            R.id.tide_row_temperature, // TextView
                            R.id.tide_row_img_up, // ImageView
                            R.id.tide_row_img_down, // ImageView
                            R.id.tide_row_img_level } // ImageView
            )
    );  

    adapter.addSection(
            "Control 2", 
            new SimpleAdapter(
                    this, 
                    controlB, 
                    R.layout.equip_row,  
                    new String[] { 
                            ITEM_TITLE, 
                            ITEM_STATE, 
                            ITEM_TEMPERATURE, 
                            ITEM_UP, 
                            ITEM_DOWN, 
                            ITEM_LEVEL }, 
                    new int[] { 
                            R.id.tide_row_title, 
                            R.id.tide_row_state, 
                            R.id.tide_row_temperature,
                            R.id.tide_row_img_up,
                            R.id.tide_row_img_down,
                            R.id.tide_row_img_level }
            )
    );  

    this.getListView().setAdapter(adapter);  

}  

}
```

all that simplicity results in this great screen:

[image: Jeff Sharkey's implementation of Sectioned ListViews]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: @KevinBrown I agree. I was a novice back then and didn't fully understand the on-topic limitations of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I managed to make it work using [cwac-merge](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge). I got help from people [here](http://groups.google.com/group/cw-android/browse_thread/thread/fff4cdeb30224c10).

I won't reinvent the wheel, so you can all read the information there (including the code used). I can clarify if needed. Just ask and I'll help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe one of the main goals of GPLv3 was to prevent people exploiting loopholes they'd found in earlier versions, so I don't think this will be a possibility.

If this is a show-stopper for you, it might be worth contacting Jeff to see if you can license code on different terms - Applying GPL to code doesn't stop it being made available by the author/copyright hold under a different license.

That said, doesn't [ExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html) and [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) do almost the same job, if you override the expand/collapse behaviour?

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: I even contacted him, but anyway... now that I've looked at everything a bit more, it's clear that his intention was really to make it available under the GPL... understandable. Truth is, I'm not that familiar with Adapters, so maybe I need to learn a bit more before asking. I'm looking into ExpandableListAdapter, but my problem is exactly the "stitching" part. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: Something similar is on my 'to do' list, if I implement it over the next few days, I'll post it here.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Meanwhile, I'm also looking into cwac-merge google group, since SeparatedListAdapter is indeed ruled out. If I manage to find a way to make it work, I'll post it here :-). I'm by no means an Android expert (or Java expert), so let's see.

Comment: Sheesh, it just force closes. Anyway... I'd guess that by now Android would provide a reusable, "no frills" code for creating headers in listviews. I'm thinking about hacking everything together in one XML and just setting "visibility.gone" on the header TextView when it's not a header, and vice-versa. Sure... I'd provide fake Strings to "flag" that, but at least it would... appear. Sorry for the rant, btw.