# Android sectioned listview with complex view

Tags: android

I  want to use [Jeff S. example](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) for sectioned listview with headers.

But I want to use more complex item view.

Can you suggest me which approach is best to do this. I found two ways

1. Put information in   `Map<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();`  using `item.put()` - [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684002/license-problem-using-sectioned-listview-with-j-sharkeys-separatedlistadapter)

2.Using `getView` on ArrayAdapter (without overriding other methods ) - [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123193/listview-with-arrayadapter-and-viewholder-adding-icons-to-the-wrong-item)

Which way is better?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of your listitems it might be better to write your own adapter by extending BaseAdapter.
[This](http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/vladimir_vivien/2011/09/creating_android_view_adapters_is_easy_but_beware_) link has a nice tutorial on how to write your own adapters.