# Sharkey's SeparatedListAdapter with ImageView?

Tags: java, android

I'm also using Sharkey's SeparatedListAdapter and have customised it quite a lot from the basic. I've added more textfields, and an imageview too, with data being pulled out of a DB. One thing I can't get my head around is how to update the src of the imageview within the adapter.

For example, this is what I have (included with the changes to Sharkey's code):

Im my **layout**, I have an imageview:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_complex_image" 
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />
```

and in my **main.java**:

```
public Map<String,?> createItem(String title, String caption, String flightno, String extra, String imagesrc) {  
    Map<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();  
    item.put(ITEM_TITLE, title);  
    item.put(ITEM_CAPTION, caption);
    item.put(ITEM_FLIGHTNO, flightno);
    item.put(ITEM_EXTRA, extra);
    item.put(ITEM_IMAGESRC, imagesrc);

    return item;  
}
```

Futher down I have:

```
        adapter.addSection(sEventDate + sExtraInfo, new SimpleAdapter(this, currentListSection, R.layout.list_complex,   
                    new String[] { ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_CAPTION, ITEM_FLIGHTNO, ITEM_EXTRA, ITEM_IMAGESRC }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.list_complex_title, R.id.list_complex_caption, R.id.list_complex_flightno, R.id.list_complex_extra, R.id.list_complex_image }));
```

Crudely, I think it's trying to set a text value to the imageview, where it takes no textvalue. I want to edit the **src** field

In Sharkey's **separatedlistadapter.java**, he has:

```
public void addSection(String section, Adapter adapter) {  
    this.headers.add(section);  
    this.sections.put(section, adapter);  
}
```

Any ideas how I can update this to also include a **src** change to the ImageView, before the item is added to the adapter?

Many thanks,
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer, for anyone else searching.

Thanks to the following post by David Cesarino:
[Post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684002/license-problem-using-sectioned-listview-with-j-sharkeys-separatedlistadapter)

Turns out I can reference the String.ValueOf() parameter of the Resource Drawable object.
So, instead of using a plain string (like for a textfield), I can set the field value to:

```
String.valueOf(R.drawable.my_shape_image)
```

Works a Charm, cheers!
J